# How would I go about getting a ComboBox(s) Value

Tags: .net, winforms, combobox

I am using Visual Studios 2019 Windows Forms c#.

So I have a ComboBox and It has Four Values lets say:
1,
2,
3,
4.

Now how would I test in real time on the form which of those is selected.
Reason for needing To test this: I have a ComboBox and I am trying to enable other combo boxes based on which option is selected. So If Option 3 is selected ComboBoxes 1-3 will be enabled

Now I know how to go about everything I just trying to figure out how to tell which option is selected.

Thanks everyone!! :)

EDIT:

Would I use:

```
        if(combobox_ComboBox.SelectedIndex == 3)
        {

        }
```

Comment: `if(combobox_ComboBox.SelectedIndex == 3)` is checking if the user selected 4 in your list.

Comment: Okay so It starts at 0?

Comment: Correct.  .Net uses zero based indexes. -1 is when nothing is selected.

Comment: Okay Cool: I just Tested this and It does't seem to work am I supposed to be putting the "if else statement" in the"        private void combobox_ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)"? Or would I put it in another Code Block?

Comment: Probably.  Where are you running it now?

Comment: Sorry I edited my comment while you where responding It is under the: "private void combo_ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)" Code Block

Comment: I also tested if the combo boxes text matched what was in the items(Collection) using an if else statement but that didn't seem to work either, that is why i am curios if it need to be in another code block.

Comment: Is the event subscribed?  Put a debug stop on your `If (...)` line and see if it hits it when you select an item.

Comment: Okay so it does in fact test for each option i select but none of the options returns as true. Would Using a NumericUpDown Work Better for this?

Comment: If you hit the debug stop, then you can hover your mouse over the SelectedIndex property and see the value. Otherwise, you have to edit your question with all the relevant code.

Comment: Okay ya pulling the properties up while debugging shows as true but then skips to the else command so i am thinking it might be a bug, and sure enough it was i just restarted visual studios and it worked with the selected index command thank you again!! :)

Comment: If you *manually* filled your ComboBox with `{ 1, 2, 3, 4}` (in the designer, maybe), when a User performs a selection and you verify that `SelectedIndex = 3`, then you know that the selection is `"4"`.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, I believe a combo box also has a text property, so you could read that property if you didn't care about the selected index, other than -1 of course.